# Extending continuous injective curves both continuously and injectively

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Let $X$ be a topological space.

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to X$ be continuous and injective.

$\gamma$ is said to be "openly extendable" if there is $[a,b]\subset (a',b')$ and a continuous and injective curve $\gamma':(a',b')\to X$ with $\gamma'\vert_{[a,b]} = \gamma$.

Under what conditions on $X$, all continuous injective curves are openly extendable?

I'm specifically interested in the case where $X$ is metrizable.

Comment: I think this holds for all Riemannian and Finalerian manifolds, and in all of Busemann’s $G$-spaces (where local prolongability is an axiom). What examples do you have in mind without this extendability?

Comment: The problem is with the injectivity. Sometimes the only way to extend the curve is to "go back through $Im(\gamma)$". For example $X=[0,1]$ and $\gamma = id_{[0,1]}$.

Comment: Is it sufficient to require that any two points have topologically isomorphic neighborhoods? My intuition in this area is not good enough to comment further.

Comment: Is there a proof that $\mathbf{R}^n$ satisfies this condition? For $n=2$ I guess this follows from a Schoenflies-like theorem (after post-composition we can boil down to a straight segment) but the latter should fail for $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @YCor Assuming my answer below is correct, $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies all the conditions required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>**EDIT 1:** Fixed the mistakes and added a full proof below</s>

**EDIT 4: Found how to prove the existence of a connected neighborhood.
I am satisfied with this proof, so I'll accept the answer**

**Theorem:** If $X$ is connected, <s>locally connected</s> **EDIT 4: locally path connected**, locally compact and metrizable and $x=\gamma(a)$ and $y=\gamma(b)$ are not isolated within $X-(Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o})$ then $\gamma$ is openly extendable.

**Proof:**

First, we want to find a neighborhood $U_x$ with $W:=U_x-Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o}$ being connected.

Let $V_x$ be a path connected neighborhood of $x$ separated from $y$.
There are three cases:

1. If $V_x-Im(\gamma)$ is connected then so is  $V_x-Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o}$ (and as $X$ is locally path connected, this neighborhood is path connected).
2. If for every path connected component $Y$ of $V_x-Im(\gamma)$ we have $x\in\partial Y$.
   Let $y\in Y$ and let $W_x$ be a path connected neighborhood of $x$, by our assumption, $W_x\cap Y\neq\emptyset$ and therefore $x$ is connected by a path to every point in $W_x$, therefore $Y\cup\{x\}$ is path connected. But as this is true for all $Y$ then $$\bigcup_{Y}(Y\cup\{x\}) = V_x\cup\{x\} = V_x-Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o}$$ is path connected (as a union of path connected spaces with non empty pairwise intersection).
3. Let $Y$ be a path connected component of $V_x$ with $x\notin \partial Y$. $Y$ is closed, and $X$ is $T_3$ which means there is a closed neighborhood $W_x$ of $x$ with $W_x\cap Y = \emptyset$.
   Let $U_x$ be a path connected neighborhood of $x$ within $W_x$.
   We assumed $x$ is not isolated within $X-(Im(\gamma)^{\mathrm{o}})$ which means there is at least one point $x\neq w\in W_x-Im(\gamma)$. As $x\notin\bar{Y}$ we have $w\notin Y$.

   Now let $Z$ be the path connected component of $w$ in $V_x-Im(\gamma)$. But now $Z\cup\{x\}$ is path connected as $Z$ is, and $x,w\in W_x$ which is path connected. But now $Z\cup\{x\} = Z - Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o}$ is path connected as we wanted.

Let $U_x$ be compact, connected neighborhood of $x$ (it exists because $X$ is locally compact and locally connected, and we can refine one neighborhood to satisfy both conditions).

**EDIT 2:** The fact that $U_x-(Im(\gamma)^{\mathrm{o}})$ is connected is not obvious, here is the explanation:

Because $X$ is $T_3$ we can choose a neighborhood which is seperated from every $\gamma([t,s])$ where $t\geq t_0>0$ which makes $U_x-(Im(\gamma)^{\mathrm{o}})$ connected (otherwise there's a closed $K\subset Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o}$ which separates $U_x$ and we know $x\notin K$ therefore it contains the image of an interval $\gamma([t,s])$ with $t>0$ and we can choose $t_0$ to be smaller than this $t$).

**End of EDIT 2**

<s>**EDIT 3:** Finding a $U_x$ for which $U_x-Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o}$ is connected is not obvious, and the argument doesn't work without it. It seems like it is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it.</s>

Due to the properties of $X$, $W$ is also metrizable, connected and locally connected, and as $X$ is Hausdorff we can choose $U_x$ to be compact which means so is $W$ (as $W = U_x \cap (Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o})^\mathrm{c}$ is closed).

Therefore the space $W$ is metrizable, compact, connected, and locally connected. Therefore it satisfies the conditions of the [Hahn Mazurkiewicz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#The_Hahn.E2.80.93Mazurkiewicz_theorem). Therefore it is a Peano space which is arcwise connected. We have $$U_x\cap Im(\gamma)^c\neq\emptyset$$ becuase we assume $x$ is not isolated. Let $z\in U_x - Im(\gamma)$

Let $g:[0,1]\to U_x-Im(\gamma)^\mathrm{o}$ be an arc between $x$ and $z$, i.e. a continuous bijection satisfying $g(0)=x, g(1) = z$. Now $g\cdot \gamma$ is continuous and injective (as both components are injective and their ranges do not overlap except at the common point).

$X$ is $T_3$, so let $V_y$ be a neighborhood of $y$ not intersecting $U_x$ ($U_x$ is compact and therefore closed). Repeating the same process for $y$ within $V_y$ extends $\gamma$ into a continuous injective $\gamma\cdot g'$ with $Im(g')\subset V_y$.

Now $\gamma':=g\cdot\gamma\cdot g'$ is injective because $V_y\cap Im(g) = \emptyset$

$Im(g)^\mathrm{o}, Im(g')^\mathrm{o}\neq\emptyset$ bacuase $X$ is locally connected, and therefore $\gamma'$ satisfies the conditions of the lemma.

**Remark:** Among other things, this condition implies $\gamma$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: is there a mistake here? let $X$ be the closed interval $[-1,1]$ and $\gamma$ the inclusion of $[0,1]$.

Comment: You're right, I may have jumped the gun, will edit soon.